# Return a value from a list of Objects in Dart based on a condition

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a list of Country objects: countryName, countryCode, currencyName, currencyCode, countryCapitalCity, countryLatitude, countryLongitude. The objects are store as follows:

```
    Country('Ghana', '+233', 'Ghanaian Cedi', 'GHS', 'Accra', 5.603717,
        -0.186964, 22),
    Country('Guinea', '+224', 'Guinean Franc', 'GNF', 'Conakry', 9.641185,
        -13.578401, 23),
    Country('Guinea-Bissau', '+245', 'West African CFA Franc', 'XOF', 'Bissau',
        11.881655, -15.617794, 24),
    Country('Ivory Coast', '+225', 'West African CFA Franc', 'XOF',
        'Yamoussoukro', 6.827623, -5.289343, 25),
```

I have instantiated the list as follows:

```
    List<Country> _countries = Country.countries;
```

I have a variable: userCountryCode which will be provided - for example take a case of +245. I want to go through the list of _countries and return the values 11.881655, -15.617794, which are mapping to the *countryLatitude, countryLongitude* properties of the object.

The following has not worked:

```
    List<Country> dumy =
       _countries.where((element) => element.countryCode == result).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing so would be using a `Map`. In your case, you could create the `Map<String, List<Country>>` being the key the `countryCode` (which I understand is not unique since you can retrieve multiple `Country`).

Then, you would only have search for the key like `mapName[countryCodeKey]` which would return a `List<Country>` which would be all contries that have that key.

This is way more faster than iteration through all the list items. If you know Big O notation, you solution is O(n) while using a map is O(1). You would only have to iterate once through the list to create the map.

To create the map, you could use:

```dart
Map<String, Country> = {
  for (Country c in _countries)
    c.countryCode: c
};
```

An example would be:

```dart
void main() {
  List<Country> _countries = [
    Country(
      'Ghana',
      '+233',
      'Ghanaian Cedi',
      'GHS',
      'Accra',
      5.603717,
      -0.186964,
    ),
    Country(
      'Guinea',
      '+224',
      'Guinean Franc',
      'GNF',
      'Conakry',
      9.641185,
      -13.578401,
    ),
    Country(
      'Guinea-Bissau',
      '+245',
      'West African CFA Franc',
      'XOF',
      'Bissau',
      11.881655,
      -15.617794,
    ),
    Country(
      'Ivory Coast',
      '+225',
      'West African CFA Franc',
      'XOF',
      'Yamoussoukro',
      6.827623,
      -5.289343,
    ),
    Country(
      'Another Country',
      '+225',
      'Atlantida',
      'BTC',
      'Bitcoin',
      12.827623,
      -155.289343,
    ),
  ];

  Map<String, List<Country>> countryMap = {};
  for (Country country in _countries) {
    countryMap.putIfAbsent(country.countryCode, () => []).add(country);
  }

  // Let's say you are looking for the +233 code
  countryMap['+233'].forEach((item) {
    print(item.countryLongitude);
    print(item.countryLatitude);
  });

  // If you want it null-aware
  countryMap['+234']?.forEach((item) {
    print(item.countryLongitude);
    print(item.countryLatitude);
  });
  // By using ?. the property or method will only be called if
  // the item is not null

  // If you want to check if a code exists
  if (countryMap.containsKey('+312')) {
    print('Existing code!');
  } else {
    print('This code does not exist!');
  }

  // If you want to keep the list of contries with a code
  List<Country> countriesWithId = countryMap['+225'];
  print(countriesWithId.length);
  // Prints 2 since there are two items with the id of +255
}
```

Comment: tried it - not working giving error; Missing selector such as '.identifier' or '[0]'. can you share working code which returns the country latitude and longitude given the country code (which is already give)? thanks.

Comment: let me try it. now that you have used foreach - and this for each has given me hell on iterating through a list of documents from firebase and it duplicates each compute, can you please look at this and if you can guide? I will appreciate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773761/computing-inside-a-foreach-loop-of-a-querysnapshot-firebase-flutter-autogrows-li

Comment: It worked. I will upvote it. What am not sure is how fast it is compared to my earlier approach. nevertheless, I will employ your style in my code. I am trying to map the same to my querysnapshot list which is giving me headache but it is not adding up. any clue?

Comment: Mark it as answer ;). I saw the question and if I come with something I will tell you.

Comment: for the other question, I actually figured it out. I will post the final answer. It really bogged me down for three days - the solution was very simple... using a for loop as well as removing duplicate QueryDocumentSnapshot, also changed position of the clearing of the list. learnt a lesson of a life time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out as I was creating the question, instead of discarding the solution, thought it wise to share - I/we may need it in future:

```
    List<Country> dumy =
        _countries.where((element) => element.countryCode == result).toList();
     for (var d in dumy) {
      var clat = d.countryLatitude;
      var clong = d.countryLongitude;
    }
```